# what is the best way to convert a relative path to an absolute path?

Tags: php

I am making a search script and want to stop any deep level search for files and folders outside of the web document root.

In case the user passes in something like `../../../../../../` I want to capture it and convert it into the absolute path that it points to, then perform some sanitation checks.

So in the example if `../../../../../` is converted to `/` I want to replace `/` with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` or any other function in PHP to push the search and lock it in the web server root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function "realpath":

> echo realpath('../../../../../../');

Comment: i do that, but it return `''` or a blank string

Comment: If the path requested doesn't exist, it will return false.

Answer (score 2):

Realpath?

[php.net realpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php)